# Making a slider with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, cycle, slide

[image: Example]

I need a slider that is composed of three groups with 3 slider inside. It will start sliding the first group (1-2-3) and after show second group... cycling all. The slider should pause on mouse over and show article and the groups will show on click. Can anyone suggest slider like this?

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google some jQuery scroll controls and try a few.

Answer (score 0):

you can build some handler for this, just as with jquery lib:

js function:

```
function screenThis(page){
$('#screen').hide("fast");
$('#screen').load("handler.php?p="+page).show();
//you can add some effects on this fcn
}
```

handler.php can be like this:

```
<?php
$page = @$_GET["p"];
$content = ''; //init
$q = mysql_query("select * from pages where id = '$page' ");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$content = $r['content'];
}
if ($content != '') echo $content;
?>
```

and html code for your menu can be like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="screenThis(somenumber/orpageid)">Article 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="screenThis(somenumber/orpageid)">Article 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="screenThis(somenumber/orpageid)">Article 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very specific kind of slider you are looking for, so i think you have to do the coding yourself.

I would suggest using a slider like [EasySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) (basic, hard to to complicated stuff) or [SudoSlider](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/) (more features, steep learning curve) to make the sliding. Both support nested sliders.

Then build all of the controls yourself, and bind them to some jQuery code to handle the sliding logic (the sliding logic triggers the sliders). The same code should of course handle the "automatic sliding".

When building the automatic sliding, i would make a list of all the "steps" the code will make, like this: {{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3} ... } in order to tell the script what it should do next every X seconds.

Hope you can get it to work.